# Awesomium multithreading / multiple instances. How to?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, web-scraping, awesomium

I want to use multiple ...um... instances (?) of Awesomium in order to simultaneously load and do some actions on 2-4 websites in different threads. Is it possible? How should I do it?

So far I came up only with something like simple local TCP server which starts clients with Awesomium instances. Some time ago I used this approach when I was doing similar thing with WebBrowser (IE). But maybe there is easier way?

Also most of the time I don't need to display it, it is something like web scraper. But sometimes for debugging purposes I would like to switch to "display mode" where everything is displayed like in WPF/WinForms controls, for this mode just 1 instance of Awesomium would be fine. I hope it is possible to somehow add WebView to WebControl.

So far I was using Awesomium only via WPF control and worked only with one website at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the .NET WebControl, you can just create multiple instances of the control which are all governed by one WebCore. Each WebControl can then process different web sites.

Comment: Yes, but I will need to synchronize with UI thread for every action with any website. I thought it could be a problem given that I want to process websites simultaneously in different threads.

Comment: What problem are you having?